# c# conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am putting together a C# Asp.net MVC site. One of the models is `SystemUser` as shown here

```
public class SystemUser : DefaultModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    [Column("FirstName")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0},{1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName);
        }
    }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Hire Date")]
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int inactive { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set;  }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

}
```

The SQL Server database table def looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SystemUser] (
[Id]                INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[LastName]          NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[FirstName]         NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[HireDate]          DATETIME       NULL,
[inactive]          INT            NOT NULL,
[ApplicationUserId] NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
[CreatedDate]       DATETIME       DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
[UpdatedDate]       DATETIME       DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
[UpdatedUserId]     INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.SystemUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Person_dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId] FOREIGN KEY ([ApplicationUserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ApplicationUserId]
ON [dbo].[SystemUser]([ApplicationUserId] ASC);
```

When using the registration page on the site, the credentials are processed in the default `AccountController`. I have modified this to also create a `SystemUser` by adding four lines of code in the Register method as shown here.

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var systemUser = new SystemUser { FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, inactive = 0, ApplicationUserId = user.Id, HireDate = DateTime.Now };
    db.SystemUsers.Add(systemUser);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

When I run process the registration, the record is inserted into the `AspNetUsers` table OK, then I receive an exception on the `db.SaveChages();` call as follows,

> The conversion of a `datetime2` data type to a `datetime` data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

```
Line 160: var systemUser = new SystemUser { FirstName =  model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, inactive = 0, ApplicationUserId = user.Id, HireDate = DateTime.Now };
Line 161: db.SystemUsers.Add(systemUser);
Line 162: db.SaveChanges();
Line 163:
Line 164: await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
```

Comment: Why are you using an ambiguous regional format like dd-mm-yyyy? I bet this worked great on April 5th but not so great on April 13th. Don't let users manually enter date strings, no matter how much documentation you put on your form, someone will do it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DATETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) is limited to January 1, 1753 00:00:00, through December 31, 9999 23:59:59.997 so just make sure that you are not passing any other values.

You can either change type of your `DATETIME` fields to [DATETIME2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) or add additional validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just alter your table to use datetime2 instead of datetime type for the HireDate column.

Comment: I don't know that this will solve the problem, if the month and day are being interpreted in the wrong order, `13-11-2015` cannot be converted to a valid datetime or a datetime2.

Comment: I see your point, validation is necessary in all cases. However, the exception may be also due to a value that is not in a given range.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how likely it is that they entered a hire date in the year 1752.

Comment: How about DateTime.Minvalue as default value somewhere?